# Azure DevOps Cloudformation update stack fails using parameters file (##[error]ValidationError: Parameters: do not exist in the template)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-cloudformation

I have an Azure DevOps build pipeline that uses the AWS CloudFormation update stack task. The CF Template refers to parameters stored in a parameters file. When deploying, the build fails as the task cannot find the parameters that I have referenced in my parameters file.

E.g. The file itself:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "EnvironmentParameter",
    "ParameterValue": "dev"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "DBHost",
    "ParameterValue": "xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com"
  }
]
```

The task references my template parameters file:

[image]

Here is the reference in the template itself:

```
"dbhostparameter"      : {
    "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
    "Properties" : {
        "Name" : "/LCS/Database/host",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Value" : {
            "Fn::Sub" : [
                "${env}", 
                {
                    "env" : {
                        "Ref" : "DBHost"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

And here is the failure output (which shows it successfully loads the template parameters file)

```
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2709027Z Updating stack with template file d:\a\1\s\parameters\parameters.template
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2709794Z Loading template file from 'd:\a\1\s\parameters\parameters.template'
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2713615Z Loading template parameters file 'd:\a\1\s\parameters_ssm_dev.json'
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2715581Z Successfully loaded template parameters
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2716132Z Setting capability CAPABILITY_IAM for stack
2020-06-29T22:37:36.2716592Z Setting capability CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM for stack
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4072822Z Stack update request failed with error: 'Parameters: [DBHost] do not exist in the template' { ValidationError: Parameters: [DBHost] do not exist in the template
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4074350Z     at constructor.extractError (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:87664)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4077291Z     at constructor.callListeners (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:95965)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4078548Z     at constructor.emit (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:95675)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4079603Z     at constructor.emitEvent (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:167913)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4080477Z     at constructor.e (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:163452)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4083390Z     at r.runTo (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:169755)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4084174Z     at d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:169961
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4086749Z     at constructor.<anonymous> (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:163722)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4087643Z     at constructor.<anonymous> (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:167969)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4088469Z     at constructor.callListeners (d:\a\_tasks\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack_7ef7cdfa-aa45-42c5-93c8-d7603643dd99\1.7.0\CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack.js:2:96071)
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4089053Z   message: 'Parameters: [DBHost] do not exist in the template',
2020-06-29T22:37:36.4089378Z   code: 'ValidationError',
```

Comment: Where do you define `DBHost`  parameter? Can you show `Parameters` section of your template?

Comment: It's at the very top of my question. The parameters file content is shown at the top. That's what's being used. This is used when you select 'local file' instead of 'inline' as the parameters source.

Comment: I mean [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) which defines allowed data types for the parameters, allowed values and more.

Comment: Ugh. Thank you, I've just realised what I've done. Accidentally deleted the parameters section of the actual CF template. I feel so stupid! Time for me to hide under a rock. Thanks for accidentally pointing out where I went wrong! :) #embaressed.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I will add an answer for future reference.

Comment: The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) can help catch these template format errors quicker as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was **missing** `Parameters section` section.

The solution was to **add the section**.

Answer (score 2):

Was missing the Parameters section of the actual CF Template. Without this, there was no reference point for the parameters file, therefore, the deployment failed.